# Jquery ui datepicker beforeShowDay css change

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I try to use datepicker to show a busy/free calendar.
I use beforeShowDay to switch between two classes, but it doesn't work. The last day apply the class for all dates.

```
var SelectedDates = {};
 SelectedDates['2014-05-04'] = true;
 SelectedDates['2014-05-03'] = true;
 SelectedDates['2014-05-02'] = true;

    $(function() {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            numberOfMonths: 3,
            showCurrentAtPos: 1,
            beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                var dateFormatted = date.getFullYear() +
                    "-" + (date.getMonth() < 10 ? "0" + date.getMonth() : date.getMonth()) +
                    "-" + (date.getDate() < 10 ? "0" + date.getDate() : date.getDate());

                console.log("date js: " + dateFormatted + " highlight: " + SelectedDates[dateFormatted]);
                var highlight = SelectedDates[dateFormatted];

                if (highlight === true) {
                    console.log("add busy class to " + dateFormatted);
                    return [false, 'Busy'];
                }
                console.log("add free class to " + dateFormatted);
                return [true, 'Free'];
            }
        });

    });
```

Here's the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/b22Bz/

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Months are 0 based in Javascript (0=January, 1=February etc), so when `getMonth()` is called on the date 2014-05-04, it will return 4 not 5.

I've modified the line of code where you set `dateFormatted` from:

```
var dateFormatted = date.getFullYear() +
                "-" + (date.getMonth() < 10 ? "0" + date.getMonth() : date.getMonth()) +
                "-" + (date.getDate() < 10 ? "0" + date.getDate() : date.getDate());
```

to:

```
var dateFormatted = date.getFullYear() +
                    "-" + (date.getMonth() < 10 ? "0" + (date.getMonth()+1) : (date.getMonth()+1)) +
                    "-" + (date.getDate() < 10 ? "0" + date.getDate() : date.getDate());
```

See an updated Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/b22Bz/1/)

Comment: Yeah! Many thanks, your explications are just perfect!